# How can I hide menu item by role in React?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redux-toolkit

I am developing a React application. I have created a menu, but I do not want users to enter some links in this menu. I only want to have menu items for admins. I get menu items with getItem. I added a role section. I want to filter these items according to the role information returned from the User Token. I need help on this.

```
export function MainLayout() {
const { userToken, userInfo, loading } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const [selectedMenu, setselectedMenu] = useState(null)
const [selectedSub, setselectedSub] = useState(null)
const [pageTitle, setpageTitle] = useState('');
const intl = useIntl();
const navigate = useNavigate();
const location = useLocation();
if (userToken) {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('userToken');
    const sub = getTokenSub(token);
    const role = getRole(token); // user or admin return
    getUser.id = sub;
    const fetchData = async () => {
        await dispatch(getUserById(getUser));
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
        const selectedKey = localStorage.getItem("selectedMenuKey");
        const selectedSub = localStorage.getItem("selectedSub");
        if (selectedKey) {
            setselectedMenu(selectedKey);
            setselectedSub(selectedSub);
        }
    }, []);
    useEffect(() => {
        setpageTitle(document.title);
    }, [location]);
}
const menuItemClick = (e) => {
    let selectedKey = e.key;
    switch (selectedKey) {
        case "menu_create_client":
            navigate("/client/create")
            break;
        case "menu_city_list":
            navigate("/city/list")
            break;
        case "menu_country_list":
            navigate("/country/list")
            break;
        case "menu_my_account":
            navigate("/myprofile")
            break;
        case "menu_logout":
            dispatch(signOut())
            navigate('/login')
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    let selectedSub = e.keyPath[1];
    localStorage.setItem("selectedMenuKey", selectedKey);
    localStorage.setItem("selectedSub", selectedSub);
}
const handleLogout = () => {
    dispatch(signOut())
    localStorage.removeItem('selectedMenuKey');
    localStorage.removeItem('selectedSub');
    navigate('/login')
};
function getItem(label, key, icon, children,role) {
    return {
        key,
        icon,
        children,
        label,
        role
    };
}
const items = [
    getItem("Kullanıcı Yönetimi", "sub1", <TeamOutlined />, [
        getItem(intl.formatMessage({ id: "menu_create_client" }), "menu_create_client", <UsergroupAddOutlined />,["admin", "user"]),
    ]),
    getItem("Sistem Ayarları", "sub2", <SettingOutlined />, [
        getItem(intl.formatMessage({ id: "menu_city_list" }), "menu_city_list", <AiOutlineMenu />,["admin", "user"]),
        getItem(intl.formatMessage({ id: "menu_country_list" }), "menu_country_list", <AiOutlineMenu />,["admin"]),
        getItem("Genel Ayarlar", "15",null,null,["admin"]),
    ]),
    getItem("Hesabım", "sub3", <UserOutlined />, [
        getItem(intl.formatMessage({ id: "menu_my_account" }), "menu_my_account", <VscAccount />),
        getItem(intl.formatMessage({ id: "menu_logout" }), "menu_logout", <LogoutOutlined />),
    ]),
];
                   
<Menu
 theme="dark"
 defaultSelectedKeys={[selectedMenu]}
 defaultOpenKeys={[selectedSub]}
 mode="inline"
 items={items}
 onClick={menuItemClick}
/>
```